# Syntax error on ; when allocating an array

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

I'm getting an error in Eclipse when trying to initialize the following array in the initializing section of my class:

```
Color[] colors;
colors = new Color[4];
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Syntax error on token ";", , expected

Where ";" refers to the semicolon on the first line.
Tried different variable types, gave the same error.
Here's some code on the official JDK tutorial section that seems the same to me:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Thanks in advance, guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a correct syntax and does compile.

(Maybe the line before is a problem. Can you post it too)

Comment: Some guy just posted something and then deleted it. This is what he posted: 
Color[] colors = new Color[4];
And for some reason, it works.
Well thanks anyway to both!
(FYI the line before was boolean Active; nothing of interest)